# Mocking HystrixObservableCommand results in real .toObservable() getting called

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, observable, hystrix

I have a HystrixObservableCommand that I'd like to mock using Mockito:

```
public class LoginWithEmailCommand extends HystrixObservableCommand<Boolean> {
    // stuff...
}
```

With a test that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    Observable<Result> mockObs;

    @Test
    public void mockwtf() {
        LoginWithEmailCommand cmd = mock(LoginWithEmailCommand.class);
        when(cmd.toObservable()).thenReturn(mockObs);
        cmd.toObservable();
    }
}
```

However, running this test results in a NullPointerException:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.toObservable(AbstractCommand.java:342)
>       at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixObservableCommand.toObservable(HystrixObservableCommand.java:35)

Why does the real .toObservable() keep getting called? Setting a breakpoint shows that the LoginWithEmailCommand object being created is a generated, proxied object...

ANOTHER CLUE: If I add this override into the ObservableCommand, mocking works:

```
@Override
public Observable<Boolean> toObservable() {
    return super.toObservable();
}
```

...is there a cleaner way to make this work than having to put unused toObservable overrides in?

Comment: See also:
https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/398

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for this, so far -- perhaps there is a cleaner way...

Step 1: Create a new BaseCommand in my package:

```
public abstract class BaseCommand<T> extends HystrixObservableCommand<T> {
    // protected ctors go here

    @Override
    public Observable<T> toObservable() {
        return super.toObservable();
    }
}
```

Step 2: Extend my commands from this base instead.

```
public class LoginWithEmailCommand extends BaseCommand<Boolean> {
    // stuff...
}
```

and now the mocks work correctly.